# is it possible to display content from cgridview to dropdown in yii?

Tags: php, yii, cgridview, dropdown

I have modified my model so that the data displayed in cgridview is unique per user, depending on the account type...

However I need to create a form from another model where I could get the data from the cgridview via dropdown...

I used this code at first...

```
<?php 
$this->widget('ext.select2.ESelect2',array(
  'model'=>$model,
  'attribute'=>'pr_id',
  'data'=>$model->searchPatient(),//function to provide data
  // or
  //'data'=>CHtml::listData(PatientRecord::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'first_name')
);  
?>
```

but it returns all of the contents of the PatientRecord model, I tried using a condition before planning to retrieve the contents from the cgridview...

```
$doctor= Yii::app()->user->id;
CHtml::listData(PatientRecord::model()->findAll( array(
                                'condition'=>'doctor_id=:doctor_id', 
                                'params' => array(':doctor_id' => $doctor)
                             )
                    );), 'id', 'first_name')
```

it didn't have an error but it didn't display anything on the dropdown either...

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is with a `;` and `)` in your model code, try this:

```
   $doctor= Yii::app()->user->id;
   CHtml::listData(PatientRecord::model()->findAll( array(
                                    'condition'=>'doctor_id=:doctor_id', 
                                    'params' => array(':doctor_id' => $doctor)
                                 )
                        ), 'id', 'first_name');
```

You should always enable error logging in local environment, this will help you find any errors in your code. Here is a [link](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.logging) on how to enable error logging.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: sorry for the late reply, that did the fix thanks :)